# How to get conversions within an email send (ExactTarget)

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm looking to implement an api call, to query conversions per sent email (Send).

Here is what I found so far:

- ExactTarget API can be queried via SOAP API,
- TriggeredSendSummary contains Conversions / UniqueConversions

So the question would be: How to TriggeredSendSummary to Send? So I can have number of conversions per email

Comment: What do you mean by `conversions`?  Clicks on a specific link?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs "Conversions" are a separate, find of old feature. I can't find the references in the new docs and I don't quite remember what they do differently (I think it involves some feedback into MC/ET to measure the conversion rate).

Comment: I'm marginally aware of the SFMC [Conversion Tracking](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/conversion_tracking/), but I'm wondering if that's what the OP is referring to.  I haven't seen any API references to it.

Answer (score 0):

Something I've done in the past is have an automation running hourly that runs a:

1. Tracking Extract for conversions
2. File Transfer to unzip
3. Import to import conversions back into SFMC DE

Then just retrieve data from the DE with API or query.